# Use first item unless specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there a variable type that is a list but also a single value unless index is specified?

```
var = [1, 2, 3]
print var
print var[1]
```

Output

```
1
2
```

The purpose is for my automation script. I have a method that is used in two ways:

1. toggle.find(get_cell("Sounds"))
2. click(get_cell("Sounds"))

In the first case, toggle will use the list of values get_cell returns to retry look up

In the second case, click just wants to use the first value in the list

Comment: Can you give more context on *why* you want this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you only care about its printed representation? What should `var * 2` do?

Comment: Check that you have not declared var before.

Comment: @MEdwin, what does that mean?

Comment: print var should give him [1, 2, 3], but he is showing it as 1

Comment: @Chris preferably that would return 2

Comment: I think you need to answer Chris_Rands' question then. There's almost certainly a better solution to whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks context and is almost certainly an X-Y problem

Comment: There's not a default object type that does this, but you could write a custom class and give it this behavior as part of the `__repr__` operator

Comment: why not just do this `click(get_cell("Sounds")[0])` because func click needs only first value

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own *custom* List class:

```
class ListWithDefault(list):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

     def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self[0])
        #this will print the list's first index when print is called to it.

     def get(self, index=0)
         return self[index]
         #this allows u to get a value at an index or without specifying it returns the first value as default
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not such thing in built-in python library but you can always implement what you desire. You have not specified all the things you need but consider some thing like code below:

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__list = []

    def append(self, value):
        self.__list.append(value)

    def __getitem__(self, indices):
        if not isinstance(indices, tuple):
            return self.__list[indices]
        return self.__list[indices[0]:indices[1]]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"MyList [{self.__list[0]}]"

    def __mul__(self, a):
        assert isinstance(a, int)
        for i, val in enumerate(self.__list):
            self.__list[i] = val * a
        return self
```

and it can be used like this:

```
myList = MyList()
myList.append(10)
myList.append(9)
print(myList)
print(myList[1])
print(myList[:])
print(myList * 2)
print(myList[:])
```

output will be:

```
MyList [10]
9
[10, 9]
MyList [20]
[20, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve what you are looking for is to modify how many arguments get_cell function can take.

```
def get_cell(sounds, return_all = False): 
    lst = [1,2,3]
    if return_all:
        return lst
    else:
        return lst[0]
```

```
first = get_cell("Sounds")
print(first) # 1

# to get just first element use as click(get_cell("Sounds"))

all_vals = get_cell("Sounds", return_all = True)
print(all_vals) # [1, 2, 3]

# to get complete list use as toggle.find(get_cell("Sounds",return_all = True))
```